# disable days of the week with react-datepicker

Tags: react-datepicker

I only want to disable the days of the week that I choose, or otherwise enable the days that I need

here is an illustrative image

[image: here is an illustrative image]

I found this code in the documentation but it doesn't work for me

```
    () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const isWeekday = (date) => {
    const day = getDay(date);
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      filterDate={isWeekday}
      placeholderText="Select a weekday"
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the day of the week to disable in [this example](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-filter-dates) from the docs on the line `return day !== 0 && day !== 6;` by changing the last number.

For instance, changing `day !== 6` to `day !== 7` will exclude only Sundays, etc.

If you want to exclude multiple days of the week, add `&& day !== [day number]` to the callback. For instance `day !== 0 && day !== 2 && day !== 5;` will exclude Sundays, Tuesdays & Fridays.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution that is quite simple:

```
        import { addDays, getDay, subDays } from "date-fns";
        import React from "react";
        import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";


        type DaysOfTheWeek = "Sunday" | "Monday" | "Tuesday" | "Wednesday" | "Thursday" | "Friday" | "Saturday";

        interface Props {
          value: Date;
          error?: boolean;
          isDisabled?: boolean;
          selected?: string;
          onSelect: (value: Date) => void;
          onChange: (value: Date) => void;
          startDate?: Date;
          endDate?: Date;
          className?: string;
          isClearable?: boolean;
          exclude?: DaysOfTheWeek[];
        }

        const DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK: DaysOfTheWeek[] = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

        const DateSelect = (props: Props) => {
          const { onChange, value, onSelect, isDisabled, startDate, endDate, className, isClearable = true, exclude } = props;

          const handleExcludedDates = React.useCallback(
            (date: Date) => {
              if (!exclude?.length) return true;
              const day = getDay(date);
              return !exclude?.includes(DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK[day]);
            },
            [exclude]
          );
          return (
            <DatePicker
              className={className}
              selected={value}
              onChange={onChange}
              onSelect={onSelect}
              disabled={isDisabled}
              isClearable={isClearable}
              minDate={startDate}
              startDate={addDays(startDate ?? new Date(), 1)}
              endDate={endDate}
              filterDate={handleExcludedDates}
              excludeDates={[new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)]}
            />
          );
        };

        export default DateSelect;
```

Now  you can easily pass an array of the days of the week

```
    <DateSelect exclude={"Monday","Friday"} {...demOtherPropsDem} />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**